# Want to pause a sorting program and then later resume

Tags: c#, multithreading, events, sorting

I am working on a program that needs to sort a few numbers in c#.
I want to pause this sorting for a while based on user input and then later resume it from where it was stopped.

I am using bubble sort to sort the numbers.
What could be the best way to pause this sorting in between?
Can it be done using threads or some events?

Answer (score 0):

Most sort algorithms can be represented as single loop and thus can be easily paused on any iteration. For bubble sort as it is pausing on outer loop may be enough, just remember where you've stopped and restart from that index.

Writing multithreaded sort is fun, but if you original one is single threaded I don't see how multithreading can help... You'd need to provide more details on what you are trying to do for better answers on multithreading/event portion.

Answer (score 0):

you can make new stream. Sort your information in this new thread.
You can pause it whe you need it.
Read more about "Thread.Suspend"

Answer (score 0):

If you're only sorting a few numbers you're not going to be able to pause it for user input--it's going to be done before any user input is a possibility unless you're using something like [Bogosort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bogosort)